# Can't open Visual Studio Code in Kali Linux

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, console

I installed VS code with

```
sudo snap install --classic code
```

And when I try to use the command "code"

```
bash: code: command not found
```

I cant finde the "code" program either, its very cluttered in the snap folder.

Comment: Perhaps try [this guide](https://www.ceos3c.com/security/install-vscode-on-kali-linux-easiest-way/) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the terminal and type:

```
snap run code
```